# How can I create a function that converts a vector of fractional odds to percentages?

Tags: r, if-statement

```
converter2 <- function(odds){
    if(grepl("/", odds) == T){
      x <- str_split(odds, "/")
      y <- as.numeric(x[[1]][1])
      z <- as.numeric(x[[1]][2])
      a <- (1 / ((y/z) + 1)) * 100 
      return(a)
    }
    else{
      x <- as.numeric(odds)
      x <- 1/(x + 1)
      return(x*100)
    }
}
```

This is the code I have been using to create a function that converts a single character fractional odds to a percentage (e.g. if you write "7/2" it will return 22.222, but it doesn't work on a vector, returning the error:

```
1: In if (grepl("/", odds) == T) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Does anyone have a good way to fix this? I was thinking of using an ifelse statement but can't figure out what will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been out of touch with R so bear with me.

sapply(vector, converter2)

This would apply the function on every element and return a vector.

Comment: Problem here though is that it is changing the row names to the original value of 'name', is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Could you please add what your vector looks like and the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is

```r
Vectorize(converter2)(c("7/22","3/7"))
```